# How can I temporarily disable my bot's speech?

Tags: botframework, bots, chatbot

I have a speech-enabled bot using the Direct Line Speech channel. For certain responses I want my bot to reply by sending text and not speaking, that is remaining silent. How do I do that? My calling format looks like this:

```
string textReplyToSend = "Hi there.";
string speak = "";
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(textReplyToSend, speak);
```

But it doesn't work for me. I have tried many different values for speak. If I leave out the speak parameter or set it to an empty string, the bot speaks using the textReplyToSend value. For other speak values, the bot speaks the value, or the speech service appears to crash and the bot gives a response totally out of context. I also experimented with SSML thinking using a pause might work, but no luck so far. How can I make my bot reply silently, sending out text only?

Answer (score 0):

I found this kludgy solution using SSML, setting volume='1'. Would be nice to find a better way.

```
string speak = @"<speak xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' 
xmlns:mstts='http://www.w3.org/2001/mstts' xmlns:emo='http://www.w3.org/2009/10/emotionml' 
version='1.0' xml:lang='en-US'><voice name='en-US-AshleyNeural'><prosody volume='1'>" +
"Ooh." + "</prosody></voice></speak>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the SetSpeakMiddleware in your code? It is used to populate the appropriate tags in case of Speech-enabled scenarios. If yes, then SetSpeakMiddleware has a property `fallbackToTextForSpeak`, which if true, automatically sets the Speak property the same as the activity.Text.
If you are using the above, then I do not think there is a direct way to avoid the output Speech.